# set! and aliasing in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have a problem understanding destructive operations within scheme that don't seem consistent. Namely why bar doesn't change in the following example

```
(define foo '(a b))
(define bar foo)
(set! foo '(c d))
foo
>(c d)
bar
>(a b)
```

However this makes the bar change by changing foo

```
(define foo '(a b))
(define bar foo)
(set-car! foo 'c)
foo
>(c b)
bar
>(c b)
```

If I understand correctly, bar is pointing at foo in its' car in both examples, but somehow the old foo does not change while using set! in the first one. I can't find an answer anywhere about how and why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`define` makes a variable. A name that evaluates to a location of an object.

```
(define foo (list 'a 'b))
```

Here `foo` might point to address `240`. When evaluateing `foo` you get `240` back so `(define bar foo)` will make a second variable that point to the same object in memory. Addresses are not shown in the REPL so you'll se `(a b)` since the REPL prints whats in address `240`.

This object in memory is a `cons` so each of those are just two pointer to **other** values in memory. Thus when you do:

```scm
(set-car foo 'c)
```

you are changing the cons located at address 240 by changing the `car` pointer from the address representation of `a` to the address representation of `c`. Since both `foo` and `bar` points to the same cons cell at address `240` they both will get the change since they point to the **same data**.

If you use  `set!` you only change what value a name is pointing to:

```scm
(set! foo (cons 'd (cdr foo)))
```

Now this will update the variables pointer from pointing to `240` to some other address. Thus you can evaluate `foo` and `bar` and see they are different values:

```scm
foo ; ==> (d b)
bar ; ==> (c b)
```

Here `foo` might be located in address `256`. Since we used the old values `cdr` in `foo` we know that the tail of those are the same:

```scm
(cdr foo)                 ; ==> (b)
(eq? (cdr foo) (cdr bar)) ; ==> #t
```

If you `set!` `bar` to a different value:

```scm
(set! bar foo)
```

Now both `foo` and `bar` point to `256` and if there are no longer uses of `240` the pair at that location might be garbage collected but since `cdr` of the original `foo` is the `cdr`, lets say address `248`, that address will not be garbage collected since it is pointed to by the `cons` in address `256`.

NB: I've changed the definition of `foo` since you are not allowed to `set-car` literals like `'(a b)` since they are immutable. `(list 'a 'b)` creates a fresh list every time that line of code is executed and you can be assured the address is not being reused in eg. `'(d a b)`.

NB2: The Scheme report tries its best to keep away from dictating how to store values. Thus they don't use the concept address in the report. Most implementations of both Scheme and CL models their data quite similar.

Answer (score 5):

Aliasing doesn't mean that `bar` points to `foo`, but rather that `bar` points to the same *thing* that `foo` points to *at the moment*.  If pictures help, here are box and arrow diagrams for what's going on.  After your setup code, you have this:

```
(define foo (list 'a 'b))
(define bar foo)
```

[image: initial]

Now if you run your first try, you create a new list and set `foo` to point to it without changing anything about `bar` or what *it* references.

```
(set! foo (list 'c 'd))
```

[image: first]

But if you run this code instead, you modify the (shared) list that both `foo` and `bar` happen to point to, at the moment.

```
(set-car! foo 'c)
```

[image: second]

Comment: IOW there is no aliasing in Scheme; `(define name value)` creates a binding for `name` and sets it to point to the *value* of the expression `value`, not at the *variable* (i.e. the binding for `value`) itself. Because it could have been a full-blown expression there, like `(+ 1 value)`, too.

Comment: Aliasing is when two symbolic names reference the same data in memory. The variables 'foo' and 'bar' pointing to the same list is an example of aliasing. Doing '(set! foo ...)' changes the reference that is 'foo', it doesn't change the aliased data structure.

I think what you're calling "aliasing" and what the OP expected was for 'bar' to be an indirect reference to the 'foo' variable itself.  No, I don't think Scheme provides any means to do that.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant; like the references in C++.

Comment: It's easy to emulate through boxes. `(begin (define foo 10) (define-sticky bar foo) (set! foo 20) bar) ; ==> 20`  == `(begin (define foo (box 10)) (define bar foo) (set-box! foo 20) (unbox bar))`. Thus the reason it doesn't exist is not that its difficult to implement.

Comment: @Sylwester [can't find docs on `define-sticky`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=define-sticky). mutating a box is still just mutating a structure ("A box is like a single-element vector, normally used as minimal mutable storage.").